# hibernate 4 Mssql 2008 limit string

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to run the following HQL query:

```
select top 1000 ent from MyEntity ent Where ....
```

but it complains on token 1000.
How can I set limit manually for MSSQL 2008 in HQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit operator is not supported in HQL queries.
you have 2 solutions :

using hql:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("FROM MyEntity where ...");
q.setFirstResult(1);
q.setMaxResults(1000);
```

using nativeQuery:

```
Query q = session.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM MyEntity where ... lIMIT 0, 1000");
```